# cannot deploy app to windows phone 8.1 device

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-2015

When I'm trying to deploy (any) Windows Phone 8.1 error I get the following error in VS2013:

```
Error   3   Error : DEP6100 : The following unexpected error occurred during boostrapping stage 'Downloading package 'FF63DEA8-0A0C-4E52-B20F-84F390C30F32'': 
DirectoryNotFoundException - The system cannot find the path specified.
```

And in VS2015:

```
 Show Details   Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error       Error : DEP6100 : The following unexpected error occurred during bootstrapping stage 'Downloading package 'EB22551A-7F66-465F-B53F-E5ABA0C0574E (NativeMsVsMon)'': 
DirectoryNotFoundException - The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I can deploy the app in Visual Studio 2013 , but in my case this is not an option because VS2013 does not support universal applicationss, so I can't open my project.

Phone is recognized by my computer, it is unlocked, I've tried resetting import export settings.

I have VS2013 update 4.

Comment: Did you try to build your project as relese, not debug?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. Don't know if this is related to your issue but I've discovered that all the mess was generated by a failed attempt to update the device OS.

In short, i was unable to update my device to the last OS version. This blocked appx installations and also VS deploys.

For reference
http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/lumia-denim-update-installation-error-8018830f-developer-preview-devices-how-resolve-1482757

The only soultion I've found is to reset the device via the recovery tool mentioned in the above link

good luck